# How to run Gnome Startup Applications in i3?

Tags: 14.04, gnome, startup, i3-wm

i3 does not launch Ubuntu's startup applications by default. It will only execute what is added to its configuration. Which command or script do I have to execute do start all the startup applications registered via the Startup Application Preferences window i.e. `gnome-session-properties`?

Comment: I'd ask here - https://faq.i3wm.org/questions/

Comment: @doug If there is a command that can be executed in order to launch all registered startup application, that is not related to the window manager very much. Do you know if such a command exists?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Gnome and other DEs startup things use the .desktop files in `~/.config/autostart` and `/etc/xdg/autostart` to know what to start.

A basic solution would be to examine these files and see what commands are executed, then manually add it to the config:

```
grep -r Exec /etc/xdg/autostart/
```

Note this includes ones that are disabled (by `OnlyShowIn`, `X-GNOME-Autostart-enabled` etc)

Another solution would be to use [`dex`](https://github.com/jceb/dex), as suggested over [here](https://faq.i3wm.org/question/2155/how-can-i-use-autostart-desktop-files-in-i3/) on the i3wm FAQ/forums

Comment: Thanks for pointing out dex. So there is no way to use the Gnome preferences window in i3?

Comment: Gnome preferences sets it up for Gnome - but I think you could get it emulate gnome by using something like `dex -a -e GNOME`, so it autostarts the apps gnome is setup to use.

Comment: That sounds good. I'll try that tomorrow. Thanks for solving my problem.